# GregorianCalendar and SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite, gregorian-calendar

I'm trying to setup a RPG that will keep track of a virtual time. After some reading GregorianCalendar seems to be the best way to do this but I have some questions and hoping someone with experience could give me some insight.

Here is what I'm trying to do. The game will start in the year 1675 and run for about 30 years. At that point the character will retire if they have survived that long. The character will be able to choose from actions I've preset for them through the coarse of the game. Some actions will be short and take a hour, others may take a week or a month. The real question comes from me using SQLite heavily. I want to save the current time as well as how long an action will take in my database. My first thought when setting this up was, if I want to start the game in Aug 15, 1675 to have my data base with 3 rows, set those fields to 8, 15, 1675. Then also have 2 more columns for the time. Pull these int via cursor and set them with something like

```
GregorianCalendar time = new GregorianCalendar();
time.set(year, month, date, hour, minute);
```

I figured I would pull how long an action takes in a similar fashion. Have an int X, and then a string to tell whether this time is in minutes, hours, days etc. Then either add this int to the int pulled from database to add to the calendar directly.

**Q:** If I add it directly to the calendar how would I pull int values from the calendar to store in database to load at a later time (when the player loads their game)?

**Q:** If I add it to the int stored in the database and set the calendar with this new int what will happen when I add enough to make the int out of scope for the calendar (Date is set to 31 but I add another day)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert from the GregorianCalendar object to/from UNIX time for example using [getTimeInMillis()](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html#getTimeInMillis%28%29) [setTimeInMillis()](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html#setTimeInMillis%28long%29). GregorianCalendar also has a [roll()](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html#roll%28int,%20int%29) method:

> Adds the specified amount to the specified field and wraps the value
>   of the field when it goes beyond the maximum or minimum value for the
>   current date. Other fields will be adjusted as required to maintain a
>   consistent date.

Comment: Can UNIX time be a negative number? Since I'm starting the game in 1675 but UNIX time starts Thursday, January 1, 1970.

Comment: To spec, no. AFAIK however the GregorianCalendar class's get/setTimeInMillis() returns values relative to 1970, so you should get negative values pre that date.

Comment: Accepting this answer as this is pretty much what I did. Took -9287841281095 Milliseconds to get the date I wanted August 5, 1675 20:05. Then I'll work with the milliseconds by adding to it, and storing/retrieving this millisecond value in my DB.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) as a substitute for the (somewhat lacking) standard java date and time utilities.  It's much more flexible.

It has functions to do date math, it supports several different calendars (ISO8601, Buddhist, Coptic, Ethiopic, Gregorian, GregorianJulian, Islamic, Julian), has support for intervals, durations and periods.  It has built in formatters that let you make your output look like just about anything you wish.

If it were me, I would use Joda and store the date in the native format presented by Joda (I don;t remember what that is right offhand) and then pull it out again and use Joda to do all the date math, as well as having it convert it to whatever calendar you wish to use for display to the user.

Otherwise, it seems to me you'd be re-inventing the wheel.

Comment: Really want to avoid re-inventing as that is what I am afraid of. Seems my best approach is to store in my DB the millisecond value of the date I want. Add to it as needed. Then use Joda or something similar to convert to a calendar to show the user the "date". Should make my storing and retrieving of date easier. Then just make myself a cheat sheet of 1 day = X milliseconds, 1 hours = Y milliseconds. That way my actions all just add milliseconds instead of some days, hours, minutes etc.