# How to convert a String to a Calendar object?

Tags: java, android, calendar, android-calendar, android-date

To store a Calendar object in SQLite database, i found that the easiest way is to convert the Calendar object to a string and store it in the database as text.

Now, the problem lies in extracting the stored date from the string.

How do I parse the string containing the Calendar object and set it to a Calendar value?

My code is:

```
    String CREATE_DOCTORS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_DOCTORS + "("
            + KEY_ID_DOC + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_DOCTOR_NAME + " TEXT,"             
            + KEY_CLINIC_ADDRESS + " TEXT," + KEY_LAST_CHECKUP + " TEXT" + ");";
    db.execSQL(CREATE_DOCTORS_TABLE);
```

where KEY_LAST_CHECKUP contains a value like this:

```
java.util.GregorianCalendar[time=?,areFieldsSet=false,lenient=true,zone=Asia/Calcutta,firstDayOfWeek=1,minimalDaysInFirstWeek=1,ERA=1,YEAR=2013,MONTH=4,WEEK_OF_YEAR=29,WEEK_OF_MONTH=3,DAY_OF_MONTH=16,DAY_OF_YEAR=198,DAY_OF_WEEK=4,DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH=3,AM_PM=1,HOUR=4,HOUR_OF_DAY=16,MINUTE=19,SECOND=47,MILLISECOND=823,ZONE_OFFSET=19800000,DST_OFFSET=0]
```

and i've stored it in a database this way:

```
values.put(KEY_LAST_CHECKUP, (doctor.getLastCheckUpDate().toString())); // last check up date
```

Now, how do i retrieve the DAY, MONTH and YEAR from the stored string?

I read about how to convert a date string to a calendar object here:
[How to convert a date String to a Date or Calendar object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43802/how-to-convert-a-date-string-to-a-date-or-calendar-object)

but my string is not just a date string. It contains a lot of other details too.

What is the best way forward?

Comment: Why you're storing Calendar, and not a Date object?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10392870/gregoriancalendar-and-sqlite for better solutions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change your data model to use a `Date`. This is the usual type to be stored in the database.

You can set the `Date` to a `Calendar` by using

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.setTime(date);
```

To retrieve the `Date` from a `Calendar` you can use

```
date = c.getTime();
```

Using a `String` to store a `Date` in a database needs formatting and parsing of the `String`s and also no comparision iside the database can be done.

Comment: I tried creating my datamodel with Date, instead of String. But then, i cannot use the put method in that situation.
That is,

values.put(KEY_LAST_CHECKUP, doctor.getLastCheckUpDate();

gives me an error saying that 
The method put(String, String) in the type ContentValues is not applicable for the arguments (String, Calendar)

Comment: @Kaushal What type is the variable `values`? Also you have to use `values.put(KEY_LAST_CHECKUP, doctor.getLastCheckUpDate().getTime());` then to get the `Date` instead of the `Calendar`.

Comment: `values` is a `ContentValues` object.
also, `doctor.getLastCheckUpDate()` is a method that returns a calendar object itself.

Comment: For `ContentValues` you can use `values.put(KEY_LAST_CHECKUP, doctor.getLastCheckUpDate().getTimeInMillis());` to store it as `long`. To set the `Calendar` again use `cal.setTimeInMillis()`.

Comment: yeah, that sounds very doable. Now if I put a `long` value using `values.put`, then i can just use the `integer` data type while creating the table in sqlite, right?

Answer (score 3):

If you would like to keep string value in `KEY_LAST_CHECKUP` column. Try to use `SimpleDateFormat`.

If you keep long value, you don't need to use `SimpleDateFormat`.

For insert :

```
SimpleDateFormat simpleFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS");
String strDate = simpleFormat.format(doctor.getLastCheckUpDate());
values.put(KEY_LAST_CHECKUP, strDate);
```

For retrieve:

```
try {
    String strDate = --> from DB
    Date parsedDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS").parse(strDate);
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    c.setTime(parsedDate);
} catch (ParseException e) {
    return "Unknown";
}
```